Onenote not embedding sway
I'm trying to embed a calendar from Sway into my Onenote, but nothing happens when I paste the shareable link from Sway into my Onenote. It just remains as a link, it does not change. The calendar is public, so is the Sway object.
Moreover, it is not embedding anything - I even tried embedding a public youtube video, it still only displays the link and not the video.
I'm using Office 2019.
Any guesses why?
